# Find a string in a file and if it matches, find another matching string before it in the file

Tags: shell, perl, search

I have a file containing data as example below:

---

Reading file1
Error1
Error2
Error3
Reading file2
Error1
Error3
Error6
Reading file3
Error2
Error3
Error6

---

I want to search for Error2 and if found, the file names of it, which are file1 and file3.

I know how to search for the matches individually, but want to know how to search backwards once a match is found for another match.

Comment: Search for the filename first, then check for each filename you find whether it has content that matches your error condition. Searching backwards is not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of the pattern you can use for this sort of problem, such as my recent answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447462/find-a-string-in-a-file-and-if-it-matches-find-another-matching-string-before-i

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the lengthy way to get the output, but sure you will get.

```
my $file_nm = "";
while( my $line = <DATA> )
{
    chomp($line);
    if($line=~m/Reading\s+(.+)/)
    {
        $file_nm = $1;
    }
    if($line=~m/Error2/)
    {
        print "$line - found in $file_nm\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
Reading file1
Error1
Error2
Error3
Reading file2
Error1
Error3
Error6
Reading file3
Error2
Error3
Error6
```

Output:

```
Error2 - found in file1
Error2 - found in file3
```

Comment: Sure... thanks champ I will update it soon. +thanks for your guidance.